# Get user's avatar with their ID in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Code

```
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member=None):
   userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
   await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```

error:
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'

Comment: Maybe try to update to the newest version

Comment: what version of `discord.py` are you using?

Comment: The newest version (2.0) doesn't have that attribute @FlexGames

Comment: My python version 3.9.7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.message.author
    em = discord.Embed(title=str(member), color=0xAE0808)
    em.set_image(url=member.avatar_url)
    await ctx.reply(embed=em, mention_author=False)
```

On responds on your comment: "AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'"

[image]

In my IDE you will see I used "client" rather than "bot", but that does not have anything to do with your code. Besides that, I am using the prefix ">" which can be obviously different for you.

Results:

[image]

Code in IDE:

[image]

Comment: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: CINEMA Plus, are you sure you used to code correctly because I am on the latest discord.py version, and this code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Bram, yes i use python 3.9.7.

Comment: Updated the code a bit, and uploaded screenshots.

Comment: Are you btw sure you are pinging the user with "@"?